# Java Text formating

Tags: java, soap

I am facing a problem while parsing the soap response i am getting back from the server.

Below is a sample screenshot of the response from the server :

[image]

I am sending a soap request to the server and getting a soap response back. I need to parse each value in the soap response and store it in the database.  Below is the code i am using for sending the soap request

[image]

So basically i have 3 issue

1. when querytext has value like like brackets or ";" --> i get error like "[Fatal Error] :1:2543: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup."
2. Secondly the querytext html escaped values instead of normal value . I need > or < and it has >
3. The formating of lines is lost. every text is next to each other . it doesnt look like sql any more

can you let me know where i am making mistake